# Is one permitted to go to a haunted house for entertainment according to halocha

Tags: soul

Is it permitted al pi halacha to visit a haunted house for fun or curiosity. And or is it a sakonas nefoshos.

Comment: Sakana nefashos? Are you talking about a pregnant woman?

Comment: Do you mean the simulated ones American non-Jews often hold in late October, or thr ruins fillled with Shin Daleds discussed in the Gemarra?

Comment: talmud in berachos says not to visit a ruined house due to mazikim

Comment: *Lichorah* this is a *dvar reshus*.